# What is this device and what does it do?

Tags: pcb, usb-device, debugging

I have this device here and I do not know what it is or what it is used for. I literally found it on the ground of a store parking lot.
I've attempted to research the item and I think it is a tool used for debugging. I also have not a clue what debugging is in even a slight sense.

Some characteristics:

- It has 2 connectors

  - One connector is a standard android jack
  - The other is a 20 pin jack
- It has 1 button

Any info on this device is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Might as well be a DIY OBDII interface missing a conversion cable against the car :-) Except that the plastic box looks mass-produced by injection molding, rather than a 3D-printed one-off. And the speaker and an internal "reset button" look weird for an OBD2 dongle. So it's probably something completely different. What VID+PID does it claim on the USB port?

Comment: it is a USB connector, not an android jack

Comment: Is there a reason you took it home instead of giving it to the store???? Somebody is probably looking for that.

Comment: If you don't know what debugging is, how can you suspect it is a debugger?

Comment: Theft alarm for some high-priced item?

Comment: Maybe a USB JTAG programmer/debugger. Not sure why that would need a loudspeaker, though. Let's just say it is art or alien.

Comment: Frr- I do not know what "PID+VID" is.
 Jstola- My fault. I'm use to hearing it referred to as an Android port/jack.
 Kyle B- It was at a shopping center with multiple stores. JRE- I used a feature on my phone, "Bixby" to snap a picture of the device and it searches the internet for similar images. After looking through the results I stumbled across debugging interfaces. This device matches some of their characteristics, and was the closest match to any results I found with or without using Bixby.  Ocrdu- I also found Jtags and after looking into them slightly, I was left with the same question

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=2029462b20

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a controller/voice box for advertising displays.

Or maybe it’s a virus vector for a worm transmitted via the USB port when you plug it into your computer.

Answer (score 2):

It's a steering wheel control box for the stereo so you can retain steering wheel controls buttons with aftermarket stereo

Comment: Why would that have a speaker in it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's a Bluetooth transmitter for your phone to your car radio. It comes with a wiring harness kit from Walmart for your car radio.